# How to put the most frequently used action on top of ActionbarSherlock list navigation?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I use ActionbarSherlock 4.3 and I intend to use its List Navigation. I checked the official guidelines of Google [here](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html) and at the Sharing data section I discovered a pretty neat solution that I'd like to accomplish: the icons are in a list and the most frequently used app's icon is on the top. I'd like to create a similar solution where the list items are ordered based on the frequency of usage and they vary. How should I accomplish that?

Comment: I think you'll simply have to keep track by using a counter per button, which you save either locally or on a server, depending on how dynamic you want everything to be.

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:showAsAction="always"`, for example:

```
<item android:id="@+id/menu_settings"
    android:title="@string/settings"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_settings"
    android:showAsAction="always" />
```

Comment: I'm familiar with this but I'm more interested in the determination of the usage frequency and putting the appropriate icon to top.

Comment: Ah, for that you will have to track user actions yourself.

Comment: I was afraid of this :( What is the best option? Save in the database the count of clicks? Any built-in support?

Comment: I'd recommend using [analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/)

Comment: It is a good approach if the user is always connected to the Internet and for global measuring of button click events. I just want the action clicks to be locally saved and comparted to each other. Maybe a custom implementation is the right way...

Comment: Hmm... Local or not, I believe changing menu locations is a bad UX in the first place :)

Comment: I'd say it more like adaptive menu locations :) Isn't it common? The example I gave in my initial post is created by Google. Isn't that based on the same adaptvie approach?

Comment: If you are talking about "FIT", then that's not what you think it is. FIT is about how to arrange **static** menus.